# How to move a Linux installation to newer hardware?

Tags: centos, upgrade, hardware-compatibility

I have an existing home server installed with CentOS 7, running on hardware and an SSD that is getting quite old. The system is Intel based:

- Core i7 4770K @ 3.5 GHz
- 16 GB Corsair Vengeance DDR3 RAM
- Gigabyte GA-B85-HD3
- Samsung 840 EVO 500 GB SSD
- Linux Kernel: 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7

I just tried booting the drive in a newer AMD Ryzen based machine, and the boot was not happy at all, almost an immediate kernel panic and lockup.

The current machine on memtest is showing a host of errors, listing in the hundreds, of random memory locations, different on every test. The SSD is listing as having bad sectors, so I'd like to upgrade the machine. How do I go about this, while keeping the current OS? What are the criteria for compatible hardware on which the OS can run?

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all: if your RAM shows errors, and so does the SSD, your current system is non-functional, and there's nothing to lose :) It also means you can't use your old system to do things like creating backups or making bootable USB thumbdrives, as there's high probability your broken RAM would interfere. So, first things first: make a backup of your current SSD.

For that,

1. get a backup medium, e.g. an external hard drive
2. use a machine without RAM errors to download a live USB medium. I do use the Fedora live installer medium, but it really doesn't matter: just needs to be a modern Linux that boots on your new PC.
3. connect the old SSD in your new PC
4. boot from the live USB medium
5. format the external medium with a modern file system (e.g. XFS, btrfs). (The fedora USB image comes with `blivet-gui` which honestly is a very good tool for such things.)
6. Use `ddrescue` to make an image in of your old SSD on your backup medium. (fedora live: you can install it using `sudo dnf install ddrescue`)
7. make the image read-only

So. That's fine. Now we know that we can throw away the old, broken SSD and not lose any more data.

Now, honestly, I'd recommend you install a new SSD in your new PC, and set up a modern Linux on that, to work from, and try to get your "old" one to work next to it. You *can*, however, just as well continue to work from your live USB.

8. make a read-write copy of that image using `cp` (bonus: if you used XFS or btrfs above, that copy will not take time or speed, it's just a mirror of the unmodified data, until you start modifying things, when the affected blocks then get an actual modified copy)
9. use `losetup -P -f /pat/to/imagefile` to let Linux scan your image for a partition table, and create a `/dev/loopNpM` for each partition.
10. use `fsck` on these partitions to repair filesystems. Some will be broken.
11. make a directory under which you'll want to mount the root file system, say /sysimage; mount that appropriate `/dev/loopNpM` there; `mount -t bind` the /sys and /proc, /dev, /run from the "host" into your /sysimage/sys, /sysimage/proc, … file systems as well.
12. use chroot to spawn a shell in that root file system pivoted to look like /; use `mount -a` in there to mount the rest of the partitions (especiall /boot, /boot/EFI)
13. You're now working practically within your old CentOS installation. Update your centOS as far as possible.
14. using blivet-gui, recreate the necessary partitions (/, /boot, …) on the new SSD. Mount them and copy over the content.
15. Do the same `chroot` trick, but with your new SSD target
16. within that chroot, run `yum reinstall kernel` to recreate the initramfs;
17. make sure /boot/efi/EFI is mounted.
18. within that chroot run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg`
19. within that chroot, run `yum reinstall grub2-efi grub2-efi-modules shim` to install the bootloader to your new SSD.

This should make your system boot as well as it can on your new hardware. BUT. There's no guarantee an olde CentOS 7 can run on new hardware.

Two options:

1. Update to a newer CentOS or Fedora
2. Run your old CentOS from a filesystem image in a VM

Answer (score 0):

Your home server sports a **VERY** old kernel and I bet this is the source of many problems when you booted it on the shiny new Ryzen system.

I think Linux could be seamless-y moved between hardware but as mandatory prerequisite, software have to be compatible with both hardware.

You can try upgrading the *starting* system and only then move it to new hardware.

Comment: won't work – the starting system has both broken RAM and storage, and tampering with that will just increase your chance of irreparable data loss

Comment: I know the kernel seems to be old in Linux terms, but it seems that RedHat and CentOS are always miles behind. Is that then to be expected or am I missing something?

Comment: it's not that redhat is miles behind - you're effectively using the pre-previous release of CentOS, so it's really very old.

Comment: I've never seen a reasonable upgrade path to CentOS 8 so have avoided it. I'm not sure how a system is intended to be maintained if each update requires rebuilding the entire system with all the customisations, software, configurations etc.

Comment: @JCollins Redhat really excels at this long-term support thing, really. What redhat backports to old kernels to keep them running on new hardware is *legendary*, not gonna lie. But your kernel is > 7 years old, and there's architectural limits to that. Wouldn't surprise me if it still actually works well, but it's definitely not guaranteed that you can run something this old. Come on, CentOS 7 was released 2014. CentOS 7 was promised to be fully updated until August 2020. It will get maintenance updates till 2024, but there's no promise to make it work on new hardware.

Comment: I mean, this is more long-term than Microsoft supports Windows for anything but certified server hardware.

Comment: I'm totally not supporting staying on the old kernel, I'd love to be up to date, I just can't see a reasonable way to get there from here without starting from scratch.

Comment: @JCollins you can do things like getting a list of all manually installed packages, very superficially sort out things you don't remember/need anymore, and try to just `dnf install` these on a fresh Fedora. Fedora certainly expects you to do a distro update once a year, but in exchange, upgrades to newer versions are pretty painless (the machine I'm writing this one was set up using fedora core 14 or so, can't remember, and been updated since).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132549/discussion-between-j-collins-and-marcus-muller).