# How to setup a Linux Installation on e.g. SSD on Hardware X and install SSD on Hardware Y later on

Tags: system-installation

I have a question similar to this one: [How to move a Linux installation to newer hardware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/683536/478318)
But without the mentioned errors and not moving an "old" system to new hardware.

I'm working on older hardware and I want to upgrade it. That means:

- Mainboard
- CPU (same architecture - amd64)
- RAM
- Graphics (currently I'm using on-board graphic Intel Core i5-3450 and would upgrade to a decidated grapic card)

So basically the main resources.

My Question:
Is it a valid practice to setup my new linux system (desktop) on a ssd in the old hardware environment to later change the above mentioned hardware and using the new installation?

Comment: you state "using the new installation" - making the initial installation irrelevant - upgrading hardware though usually isn't an issue

Comment: It usually works, but not always. Obviously, the processor architecture must be the same (for example 'amd64' for PC computers or 'arm' for RPi). But some hardware may also cause problems, for example graphics and wifi chips that need a proprietary driver. And for example Ubuntu Server sets the network specifically for the hardware address while Ubuntu Desktop probes for it at boot and is therefore portable between computers. - So you can always try, in my experience what you ask for is often working.

Comment: @JaromandaX: I do not know what you mean by "making the initial installation irrelevant". My idea is to setup an new installation now and to buy the new hardware maybe in 4-5 months. But if you are saying that upgrading hardware is usually not an issue, this would answer my question to the point.
I remember ages ago that this kind of procedure did not work on Windows. I think it was Windows XP. But I'm kind of cured from that OS :-)

Comment: @sudodus: Ok. I got that. I will sharpen my question.

Comment: @superurmel, Yes, it is likely to work with a system that works like Ubuntu Desktop (I'm thinking of the network management, at least wired network, while Broadcom wifi network may need (different) proprietary drivers).

Comment: In the worst case you need a fresh installation, but keep the /home directory (for example as a separate home partition). That way many settings and personal data will be preserved, but you must install application programs again and redo some global settings again.

Comment: `I do not know what you mean` - you said you wanted to do a **new installation** ... old installation is irrelevant if you do a new one - pretty obvious